# Making Webpage accessible to my ftp

Tags: directory, www

What is the best way to make my /var/www/ folder accessible to my ftp in setting up a web page?  Making it so I can edit and upload?
In the future I will go to virtual host but that is a long way away.
Should I just chown the whole www to me?
I just don't want to sudo to edit my webpages from the terminal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use FTP - it's insecure. Of course there's FTPS, but its really secure configuration works well only with a small number of FTP clients.

You should rather create separate account for your webpage, put your webserver user in the same group and make SFTP (SSH) access, using SSH keys.

For example you can create your user like so:

```
sudo useradd -m -d /home/youruser -s /bin/bash youruser
```

Next prepare www directory:

```
sudo mkdir /home/youruser/www
chown youruser.youruser /home/youruser/www
chmod 750 /home/youruser
```

Next, put webserver user in the group, so it can reach your website.

```
sudo usermod -a -G youruser www-data
```

Install OpenSSH Server with fail2ban (brute-force protection).

```
sudo apt install openssh-server fail2ban
```

Remember to [harden your OpenSSH](https://linux-audit.com/audit-and-harden-your-ssh-configuration/).

Next, generate your SSH key and put it in your user homedir, according to this how-to: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

This way you'll have secure access to your webpage files.

Comment: Would that also be with using the IP address for it?
My Pages are not exposed to the web, I do not have the access to the router to expose it to the web so I haven't got a domain name.  
I just want to use it to get back into perl programming and other things! 
I now live in Japan, and haven't figured out how to take control over a router!

Comment: Yes, this setup will work for you.

Comment: Will I have to change the path in sites-available/000-default.conf
to point to /home/me/www in order to get the IP address to point there?

and would i have to change the path of default-ssl.conf?

Comment: That's right, you need to change the DocumentRoot to match `/home/me/www` for the default vhost. If you don't use SSL (HTTPS), you don't need to change default-ssl, but in case you do, you should change it as well.